# If X is a topological space with C a collection of connected subsets of X, then the union of C is also connected

Tags: general-topology

[image]

This is the problem. I tried doing this using this property but its not working. 
Can someone help me on this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked before: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000408/union-of-connected-sets-also-connected has correct answers to a slight generalisation of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\bigcup \mathcal{C}= U \cup V$ where $U,V$ are separated subsets.

Suppose WLOG $x \in U$. Then for each $C \in \mathcal{C}$ we know

$$C=(C \cap U) \cup (C \cap V)$$ and these right hand sets are also separated (as subsets of $U$ and $V$ resp.) $x \in U \cap C$  by assumption so the $C \cap V = \emptyset$ or $C$ would be disconnected, which it is not. It follows that $C \subseteq U$.

As $C$ was arbitrary in $\mathcal{C}$, $\bigcup \mathcal{C} \subseteq U$ and $V$ is empty, and so $\bigcup \mathcal{C}$ is connected.

Comment: I think $D$ and $p$ above may be typos.

Comment: how did you get C = (C $\cap$ U) $\cup$ (C $\cap$ V) ? Is it De-Morgans law?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun N0, right to left inclusion is trivial, and if $x \in C$, it's in the union, so in $U \cup V$ etc.

Comment: I got it finally, god knows why I was overthinking on a petty issue. Its a set theoretic statement: A $\cap$(B $\cup$ C) = (A $\cap$ B) $\cup$ (A $\cap $C), se theory its not even topology. lolz :P

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun in general topology a lot of stuff reduces to set theory. One should know quite a bit about (basic) set theory.

Comment: x∈U∩C  by assumption so the C∩V=∅ or C would be disconnected, which it is not. It follows that C⊆U. How did you get this? I know that u assuming x in the intersection of U and C, that means x $\in$ U and x $\in$ C. After that, how did you get C $\subset$ U ?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun if $C\cap V$ were non- empty, $C$ would be disconnected, as a union of two non-empty separated sets. But $ C$ is connected so that intersection is empty and so all points of $ C$ lie in $U$, none can be in $V$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105427/discussion-between-math-is-fun-and-henno-brandsma).